# JBOSS EAP 6.1 integration of Websphere MQ 8.0.0 parsing error

Tags: java, jboss, ibm-mq

I am trying to integrate wmq.jmsra.jar version 8.0.0, into JBOSS 6.1EAP.
I get a parsing error when I deploy this jar, with older version of wmq.jmsra.jar it works. I don't understand, can you help me?

StackTrace :

```
11:50:36,808 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."wmq.jmsra.rar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."wmq.jmsra.rar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "wmq.jmsra.rar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS010443: Failed to parse service xml ["/C:/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/wmq.jmsra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.RaDeploymentParsingProcessor.process(RaDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.RaDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(RaDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: resourceadapter-version
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.RaParser.parseConnector10(RaParser.java:278)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.RaParser.parse(RaParser.java:165)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.RaParser.parse(RaParser.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.RaDeploymentParsingProcessor.process(RaDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:115)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter v8.0.0.0 is targetted at JavaEE7 (because it's a JMS2.0 compliant) adapter. JBOSS 6.1 won't be able to support it so please use WMQ 7.5 resource Adapter

Comment: I download it and now I can't deploy it . ERROR CommonServices has not been initialized. there is errors with the 7.5 too.

Comment: Can you post some more diagnostics please?